# Dynamic refresh of shopping cart using AJAX?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, e-commerce, shopping-cart

Have a small problem here in WP eCommerce. When I add items to my cart, my cart widget reflects the changes immediately using AJAX. However, if there are items in my cart and I refresh the page, my cart shows "0 items" by default (when there are still actually items in my cart). Then when you add a new item, the AJAX call is made, and my cart refreshes (adding the new item).

My question is, how do I refresh my cart without actually adding an item? By calling the script below, I was able to add a blank item to my cart with a value of $0, but this is pretty hacky. I just need to send an AJAX call to refresh my cart dynamically, but not actually add anything to it. Any ideas?

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('refresh-cart').click()">

    <form class="product_form">
        <input type="hidden" name="wpsc_ajax_action" value="add_to_cart">
        <input id="refresh-cart" name="Empty" type="submit">
    </form>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could call your ajax function at certain intervals fr refreshing cart:

```
var intervalID = setInterval(function(){your_ajax_function();}, 5000);
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is place is what you trying to do is not a valid e-commerce approach and this can lead to many other issues.
what you are talking about is i believe is mini-cart and on page refresh if its showing total quantity as zero than either there is some problem in your code or in the implementation of mini-basket.

mu suggestion would be to debug the issue which is causing this problem rather than going for a heck :)